# Set value for FME RandomPointGenerator

Tags: fme-form

Basically my question is quite simple:

- I want to create certain amount of random points within polygons. The RandomPointGenerator does almost exactly what I want, but I'd like to pass the *Number of Points* from an attribute value that I have in one of the shapefiles I read in to the workspace. Now the transformer only allows to "hard code" the value in there.

Any ideas how to solve this? I'm not very familiar with using published/private parameters so maybe those could help? Or should I "manually" create the workflow of random point generation within polygons and ditch the RandomPointGenerator?

Comment: Not trying to send you away from this site, but why not post your question here: https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/index.html - I know that the guy who created that custom transformer is a regular contributor there.

Answer (score 1):

I have two possibilities to handle this.

The first one is to outsource the random point generation: Create a wrapped workspace that has an own public parameter (number of points to create) and which reads a featureclass with the area features. From here you can call the `RandomPointGenerator` using the published parameter. Write the result in an new featureclass. Call this wrapper workspace from your original workspace by using the `WorkspaceRunner` and pass your attribute value to the published parameter of the wrapped workspace and import the newly created “random point featureclass”. This is a little bit complex but it could work.

The second solution is to edit the `RandomPointGenerator` (please verify if you are allowed to edit due to license restrictions). Edit the RandomPointGenerator transformer by modifying the published parameter `NUM_POINTS`. Set the Type to `Attribute Name`. Now you should be able to pass an attribute to the `RandomPointGenerator`. Please note that this is untested.